# Spring Data MongoDB interface-based projection recursively

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to work with an interface-based projection recursively, However it is not projecting on the appropriate subfields, but only on the whole nested object.

Consider the document / collection class:

```
@Document
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;

    static class Address {

        private String zipCode, city;

        // getters and setters
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

The closed projection:

```
public interface PersonSummary {

    String getFirstName();

    AddressSummary getAddress();

    interface AddressSummary {

        String getCity();
    }
}
```

However when I'm using the following repository query:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Person, String> {

    Flux<PersonSummary> findAll();
}
```

The query is executed with the following fields: `fields: Document{{firstName=1, address=1}}` instead of `fields: Document{{firstName=1, address.city=1}}`

What are we doing wrong and is there some solution how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

According to Mark Paluch (@mp911de) at Gitter this is not yet possible, so I filed an improvement request at jira.spring.io, see: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1989